# React image path from the data in useContext, but the image is broken

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am making a blog Component with React.

By giving createContext to a separate blogData.jsx, the contents of data.JSON were brought as it is. (It was put in a variable)

Since the value of the "thumbnail" key is '/assets/post-img1.jpg' and in my Local it is '../../assets/post-img1.jpg', So I wrote the following in Post.jsx.

```
// Post.jsx
<img
    className="postImg"
    src={`../..${thumbnail}`}
    alt=""
/>

<img src={`../..${profileImg}`} alt="" />
```

The results confirmed in Developer Tools Elements are as follows. Path is correct.

```
// in Developer Tools Elements
<img class="postImg" src="../../assets/post-img6.jpg" alt="">
<img src="../../assets/profile.jpg" alt="">
```

However, the image is not rendered and an alternate image(x box?) is displayed.

```
react-blog
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── node_modules
├── public
│   ├── data.json
│   ├── index.html
│   └── reset.css
│
└── src
   ├── assets
   │   ├── post-img1.jpg
   │   └── ...
   │
   ├── components
   │   ├── banner
   │   ├── footer
   │   ├── post
   │   ├── posts
   │   ├── sidebar
   │   ├── thumbnail
   │   └── topbar
   │
   ├── contexts
   │   └── blogData.jsx
   │
   ├── pages
   ├── App.jsx
   └── index.js
```

blogData.jsx ↓

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

const blogData = createContext(
    {
        "blog": {
            ...
        },
        "posts": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "thumbnail": "/assets/post-img1.jpg",
                "title": "Dipisicing elit. Inventore illum nostrum perferendis.",
                "mainBg": "/assets/post-background1.jpg",
                "category": ["Life", "style"],
                "profileImg": "/assets/profile.jpg",
                "contents": [
                    {
                        "type": "p",
                        "text": "Adipisicing elit. Inventore illum nostrum perferendis voluptas, voluptate soluta corrupti dolore quidem. Placeat, eaque! Exercitationem est facilis dolor quas odio cum incidunt repudiandae vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Inventore illum nostrum perferendis voluptas, voluptate soluta corrupti dolore quidem. Placeat, eaque! Exercitationem est facilis dolor quas odio cum incidunt repudiandae vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Inventore illum nostrum perferendis voluptas, voluptate soluta corrupti dolore quidem. Placeat, eaque! Exercitationem est facilis dolor quas odio cum incidunt repudiandae vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Inventore illum nostrum perferendis voluptas, voluptate soluta corrupti dolore quidem. Placeat, eaque! Exercitationem est facilis dolor quas odio cum incidunt repudiandae vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Inventore illum nostrum perferendis voluptas, voluptate soluta corrupti dolore quidem. Placeat, eaque! Exercitationem est facilis dolor quas odio cum incidunt repudiandae vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Inventore illum nostrum perferendis voluptas, voluptate soluta corrupti dolore quidem. Placeat, eaque! Exercitationem est facilis dolor quas odio cum incidunt repudiandae vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Inventore illum nostrum perferendis voluptas, voluptate soluta corrupti dolore quidem. Placeat, eaque! Exercitationem est facilis dolor quas odio cum incidunt repudiandae vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Inventore illum nostrum perferendis voluptas, voluptate soluta corrupti dolore quidem. Placeat, eaque! Exercitationem est facilis dolor quas odio cum incidunt repudiandae vel."
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "img",
                        "src": "/assets/post-background1.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "p",
                        "text": "Inventore illum nostrum perferendis voluptas, voluptate soluta corrupti dolore quidem. Placeat, eaque! Exercitationem est facilis dolor quas odio cum incidunt repudiandae vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Inventore illum nostrum perferendis voluptas, voluptate soluta corrupti dolore quidem. Placeat, eaque! Exercitationem est facilis dolor quas odio cum incidunt repudiandae vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Inventore illum nostrum perferendis voluptas, voluptate soluta corrupti dolore quidem. Placeat, eaque! Exercitationem est facilis dolor quas odio cum incidunt repudiandae vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Inventore illum nostrum perferendis voluptas, voluptate soluta corrupti dolore quidem. Placeat, eaque! Exercitationem est facilis dolor quas odio cum incidunt repudiandae vel."
                    }
                ],
                "userName": "Chilli",
                "created": "2022.04.01"
            },{...},{...},{...},{...},{...}
        ],

        "users": [
            {...},{...}
        ]
    }
);

export default blogData;
```

Post.jsx ↓

```
import "./post.css";

export default function Post({data}) {
    const {id, thumbnail, title, category, contents, profileImg, userName, created} = data;
    return (
        <div className="post">
            <img
                className="postImg"
                src={`../..${thumbnail}`}
                alt=""
            />
            <div className="postInfo">
                <dl className="postCats">
                    <dt className="hidden">Category</dt>
                    <dd className="postCat">
                        {category}
                    </dd>
                </dl>
                <h3 className="postTitle">
                    {title}
                </h3>
                <dl className="authorWrap">
                    <dt className="hidden">Author</dt>
                    <dd className="author">
                        <img src={`../..${profileImg}`} alt="" />
                        {userName}
                    </dd>
                    <dt className="hidden">post date</dt>
                    <dd className="postDate">
                        {created}
                    </dd>
                </dl>
                <p className="postDesc">
                    {contents[0].text}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Posts.jsx ↓

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import Post from "../post/Post";
import "./posts.css";
import blogData from "../../contexts/blogData";

export default function Posts() {
    const { posts } = useContext(blogData);
    const postArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
        postArray.push(<Post key={i+1} data={posts[i]} />);
    }
    console.log('postArray', postArray);

    return (
        <div className="posts">
            {postArray.reverse()}
        </div>
    );
}
```